# Why does my regex not work?

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to scrape titles from a html page, I am using regular expression to fetch the titles as follows:

Regex:

```
<h6 class="panel-title"><i class="icon-file-music2"><\/i>(.*?)<i class=" icon-info3 text-success" data-popup="tooltip" data-html="true" title="(.*)" data-placement="bottom"><\/i>\n<\/h6>
```

The code to parse:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h6 class="panel-title"><i class="icon-file-music2"></i> TRXD - Sometimes.mp3
<i class=" icon-info3 text-success" data-popup="tooltip" data-html="true" title="<b>Uploaded on:</b><br/> 2017-11-14 06:56:54<br>  <b>Downloads:</b><br/> 7" data-placement="bottom"></i>

</h6>
                                    </div>
```

[Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/aENLJ7/1)

The section I am trying to get back is `TRXD - Sometimes.mp3`. The regular expression I have used doesn't seem to work, would appreciate someone explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - Don't parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool - Use something that will load the DOM and go from there

Comment: You need to enable the single-line modifier `s` and add a 2nd newline at the end: `\n\n<\/h6>`

Comment: @Rawing Please convert to an answer. Thanks

Comment: This question won't be useful for any future readers. Rather than answering it, I'd rather close it as a typo/unhelpful.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example: https://regex101.com/r/6uWm8E/1, you are missing new lines captures.